# Bulk Job Status - Failed vs Not Processed?

Tags: bestpractice, bulk-api, documentation

**What are the use cases for setting a Bulk (version 1) job to a status of Failed vs Not Processed?** 
[Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=monitoring_async_api_jobs_details.htm&type=0) gives the same description for both

> The batch failed to process the full request due to an unexpected
>   error, such as the request is compressed with an unsupported format,
>   or an internal server error.

Specifically, my use case is when a [transformation spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_mapping.htm) fails to be added to an upsert job (malformed, invalid field names, or similar). I'd like my custom code to gracefully close the job so it doesn't hang open but also conveys the unexpected nature of the closure as concisely as possible.